# To calculate $Tor_1^G(\mathbb{Z},N_{ab})$ and $Tor_1^Q(\mathbb{Z},N_{ab})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. I wish to calculate $Tor_1^G(\mathbb{Z},N_{ab})$ and $Tor_1^Q(\mathbb{Z},N_{ab})$, where $Q=G/N$. I could not found any lecture notes or book which calculate the first homology group $H_1(G,N_{ab})$ or $H_1(Q,N_{ab})$. How can I calculate them?
Is there any bound for these groups?

More precisely, I am interested for group of order $p^5$. I feel that for such groups $H_1(Q,N_{ab})$ will be easier to compute but I do not know any method.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use a long exact sequence in homology arising from a short exact sequence in the following way: the group $N$ has order $p^a$ for some $a$. Therefore, $\textit{as a $G$-module}$ (or as a $Q$-module) it has a filtration in which the subquotients are isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ upon which $G$ (or $Q$) acts trivially. Now, $H_1(G,\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is the biggest elementary abelian quotient of $G$ and $H_0(G,\mathbb{Z}/p)=\mathbb{Z}/p$. By carefully using the long exact sequences arising from the filtration it is possible to calculate the thing you wish for, in case $G$ and $N$ are given explicitly enough.